# CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect. error while submitting the foobar solution in Google's foobar platform

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome, csrf

I was trying to test run  my python solution in Foobar platform using verify solution.py option . But I am continuously getting this error : 'CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect.'

Should I change my cookie preferences ?

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling cookies in your browser and reloading the page.